# Controlling in-call audio in Android SDK/NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-sdk-2.3, equalizer

I have a need for an equalizer than controlls in-call audio and not just music , is that possible ?

Several options I can think of off the top of my head :
1.) If there's a built in option for equalizers to control calls
2.) Creating a service over a bluetooth headset and filtering the audio myself using the SDK or the NDK ( if at all possible )
3.) Creating an app that filters the audio itself

Are any of these actions possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a need for an equalizer than controlls in-call audio and not just music , is that possible ?

No. You have no access to the in-call audio stream.

Comment: Not even if I track audio data going to an ear-piece to improve audio quality ?

Comment: @DanielBatkilin: You cannot "track audio data going to an ear-piece to improve audio quality", either, AFAIK.